# Error when I try to convert Json String to Object DTO in Java

Tags: java, json, object, parsing, dto

I am trying to convert a JSON to a disc that I already have implemented in my code and in this way be able to access the values of the properties with which the disc will remain to build a logic in another part of my code, thank you your help as i have been trying for several hours and i always get this error,

Additionally I attach the JSON, my DTO and the error to see if you know why I am getting the error, thank you

This is the Json I am trying to convert

```
{
  "TaxID": "123456798",
  "DocumentType_Ext": "C",
  "creationDate": "",
  "name": "William",
  "firstLastName": "Dan",
  "tagType": "client",
  "email": "noaplica@gmail.com"
}
```

My DTO Object

```
  @JsonProperty
  @Required
  public var TaxID            : String

  @JsonProperty
  @Required
  public var DocumentType_Ext : typekey.IdentificationType_Ext

  @JsonProperty
  public var creationDate : Date

  @JsonProperty
  public var name : String

  @JsonProperty
  public var firstLastName : String

  @JsonProperty
  public var tagType : typekey.ContactTagType

  @JsonProperty
  public var email : String
```

Implementation class for parsing

```
  var result = false
    var parserJSON = new JSONParser()
    var gson = new Gson()
    var json = parserJSON.parse(new String(body))


    try{

      result = InboundMessageUtil.validateMessageNull(json)
      var message = gson.fromJson(json, ContactBasicRequest)
```

Outpout Error

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 22
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to add the source for ContactBasicRequest and its components

Comment: Hello @tgdavies, the ContactBasicRequest class was the one I added in the question as "My DTO Object" is above